# How to convert date format to dd/MM/yyyy in C# where my SQL Server date format is in yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date, datetime

I am using a stored procedure which has `DateTime` in yyyy/MM/dd format, but I want to convert that in my code behind into dd/MM/yyyy format. Can anyone help me with this?

```
txtstart.Text =  "01" + "/01/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() ;
txtend.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: If I get this correctly neither the duplicate answer, nor the answers below are good solutions for you... The answer is: **Do not deal with DateTime on string level!** Your **SQL Server doesn't have a date format!** Similar to C# a DateTime is not stored as the string you see, but in a binary format. The **string is for presentation only**. Use properly typed parameters!

Comment: change txtend.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); to txtend.Text = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); or use toShortdateString() method

Comment: Thanks Saurabh :)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
txtend.Text =  DateTime.ParseExact("your date", "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi Innoval, Thanks for your reply.I need 'System.DateTime.Now'

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimes [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) Method to convert your original string to a DateTime value and then use ToString with a pattern to convert that DateTime object to string in your needed format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting DateTime in yyyy/MM/dd format from a database and wanted to convert it to dd/MM/yyyy. If so, see if the below one helps you,

```
string dateTimeFromDB = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
string dateTimeInCorrectFormat = 
Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeFromDB).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

However, check for FormatException and other needed defensive checks before and while formatting.

Comment: Hi Shankar..I have used your code and passed the DateTimeInCorrectFormat to my TxtEnd..It is showing 'Procedure of function expects parameter '@Enddate', which was not supplied'

Comment: Is the assignment failing with 'Procedure of function expects parameter...' ? See if the assignment of DateTime (dateTimeInCorrectFormat) to txtEnd.Text is successful. The message 'Procedure of function expects parameter...' is a DB access message and perhaps not from the assignment itself.

Comment: Yes I have debugged,the txtend passes the correct fromat what i need